# ClickAt vaadin table with Selenium IDE

Tags: vaadin, selenium-ide

I am able with Selenium IDE to click on vaadin 2nd table row defined absolutely like this:

ClickAt | //div[@id='gwt-uid-14']/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div

BUT how can I tell to Selenium IDE; Click at table row with text "Example"?
(or click at table row where text in column named "Column1" is equal to "Example")?

Answer (score 0):

No answer, so I found the solution by myself:

clickAt   //div[@id='gwt-uid-14']//tr/td[div/text()='Example']